# php git http-push protocol

Tags: php, git, url, push

I'm trying to create a little php based web interface for git. I'm using the "Laravel"
 framework.

At the moment i can clone and pull, but i cant figure out how to catch the git push command. 
I cant find any documentation on this on the [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/) website

Is there a place where i find some proper documentation on how the URL and post data are organized on a push so i can implement this as i'm not creating the repository's in the 'apache webroot'.

Answer (score 0):

Customize "git-receive-pack" OR "post-receive" and "pre-receive" hooks